# allow new users to post an article before they sign up

Tags: posts

I am new to wordpress development but I can get it done if I am guided on the right direction.
I have allowed subscribers to post articles on my site.Now I am trying to allow them to post BEFORE they sign up.

so step 1 : land on site and click submit article
step 2 : fill up the form 
step 3 : are you registered? signin here or sign up and form appears for them to sign up after they hit submit, it submits their article + signs them up
anyway to do this ?

Comment: Hi fogsy, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: I tried a couple of plugins for guest blogging but its not working exactly like what I am trying to achieve which is if they dont sign up then the article shouldnt be there. i am not sure if there is an easy way to do this ?

Comment: You need to have custom code for that, Most of the Guest Posting plugin allows you only guest posting and not signing up after the article. If you are a developer you can easily modify plugin for personal use

Comment: yeah thats what Im thinking I was wondering if there was something available to be used like a plugin. but I guess I have to code it myself thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin http://wedevs.com/plugin/wp-user-frontend-pro/
Had some projects with this on board. Really cool thing.

Where is a guest and registered users posting ability. I think you can add register form somewhere along article inputs.